# Memcachier add-on for cloudcontrol is failing

Tags: cloudcontrol, memcachier

I followed the installation guide at https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Add-on%20Documentation/Data%20Storage/MemCachier. The memcachier server is up and running, I tested it from the command line. But my cloudcontrol app isn't able to access it.

Here's the error in our logs:

```
Info MemcachedError: error 40 from memcached_set: FAILED TO SEND AUTHENTICATION TO SERVER, no mechanism available, host: [my-memcachier-server-url]:11211 -> libmemcached/sasl.cc:221
Notice No worthy mechs found
```

This seems to be a SASL-related issue. Is it possible that cctrl does not have the correct sasl2 libraries installed? Did anyone else experience this problem?

Further info:

- django-pylibmc==0.5.0 and pylibmc==1.4.1 in requirements.txt
- url and credentials are read from the cctrl environment correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the libmemched version bundled with the buildpack missing a patch (https://bugs.launchpad.net/libmemcached/+bug/1381160). Because it is a stackoverflow bug, it can work systematically on your machine while it systematically breaks in the container. I will update the python buildpack to use the patched libmemcached library from the stack.

In the meantime you can try to achieve this manually by setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to /usr/local/lib either via config add-on or `web: env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib <your_command>` in the Procfile.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem on Heroku with memcachier. Is there a similar soln for heroku?